# Modeshape binary store in where?

Tags: jcr, modeshape

First i config my modeshape configuration file like this:

```
"storage" : {
        "persistence" : {
            "type" : "db",
            "connectionUrl": "${database.url}",
            "driver": "${database.driver}",
            "username": "${database.user}",
            "password": "${database.password}",
            "tableName": "GOVERNANCE_MODESHAPE",
            "poolSize" : 5,
            "createOnStart" : true,
            "dropOnExit" : false
        }
}
```

After I create a node and set a property for it and save it in my local environment, I can still find the node and the property in my local environment. But it will can't be found in my colleague local environment.

Then I change the configuration like this:

```
"storage" : {
        "persistence" : {
            "type" : "db",
            "connectionUrl": "${database.url}",
            "driver": "${database.driver}",
            "username": "${database.user}",
            "password": "${database.password}",
            "tableName": "GOVERNANCE_MODESHAPE",
            "poolSize" : 5,
            "createOnStart" : true,
            "dropOnExit" : false
        },
        "binaryStorage" : {
            "type" : "file",
            "directory": "/var/thinkbig/modeshape",
            "minimumBinarySizeInBytes" : 5000000
        }
    }
```

I can find the node and property which created in my local environment, and my colleague also can find it in his local environment. But i can't find the directory of path /var/thinkbig/modeshape.

So I want to know the modeshape binary store from where? Why I add the "binaryStorage" config in the configuration file, everybody can find the node and property? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per the doc for  [minimumBinarySizeInBytes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE50/Built-in+binary+stores)the minimum size (in bytes) above which binary values will be stored in the store. Any binary value lower in size will be stored together with the other node information..

This means that binaries smaller than the specified size are stored in the database, rather than the file system. You could change this to a value of 1 byte if you want to ensure that all binaries get stored in the file system .